# building a multi dimentional array from mysqli database query using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I am trying to build a multi dimentional array of students and their data from my database table using mysqli and php.

I want my array to look something like this

```
Array #$adult array
(
    [626] => Array #student no 626 data
        (
            [name] => emily,
            [age] => 43,
            [height] => 156,
        )
    [627] =>   #student no 627 data
        (
            [name] => luke,
            [age] => 31,
            [height] => 176,
        )
)
```

the number being the members id followed by their data.

So i have tried the following

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pzgym_waitinglist WHERE seen = 0 GROUP BY gym_discipline, school_yr, id";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    #set up array
    $adult = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
    {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $age= $row["age"];
        $height = $row['height'];

        if($row['gym_discipline'] == "Adult Gymnastics")
        {
            $adult[$id] = "['name'] => $name, ['age'] => $age, ['height'] => $height";

        }
    }
}
```

but this isnt producing the correct results, so im guessing my array building sucks :( here is what i am getting.

```
Array
(
    [626] => ['name'] => Emily, ['age'] => 43, ['height'] => 156
    [627] => ['name'] => Luke, ['age'] => 31, ['height'] => 176
)
```

Could someone help me please to build a successful multi dimentional array from the data im my database

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a second level when you create the array, instead of just simply adding keys and data to the array.

So, first create an *index (key)* with the student ID, then the *value* of that new *index* will be a sub-array with all the data for that student.
Then next loop it will do the same for the next student.

Something like:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $age= $row["age"];
    $height = $row['height'];

    if($row['gym_discipline'] == "Adult Gymnastics")
    {
        $adult[$id] = array(
           "name" => $name, 
            "age" => $age, 
            "height" => $height,
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: No problem :) it's fairly straight forward in that an array has keys and values, and the value can be an array too.

Comment: :) i was so close at one point lol, my mistake was i tried wrapping the keys in [] like ['name'] => $name which obv didn't work :(

Comment: Trial and error :) You can't figure everything out, trying to first is the key, though, as then you'll likely understand better when the solution is presented to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `array` construct:

```
$adult[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'age' => $age, 'height' => $height);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do in following manner--

```
$adult[$id]['name'] = $name;
$adult[$id]['age'] = $age;
$adult[$id]['name'] = $height;
```

Note:- if condition is not required because your array is created through id.